# Use QUERY Function to Count Unique Data Points

Tags: function, google-sheets, unique, dashboard

Using Google Sheets for this on a Mac

Both columns A and B are text data and not numerical data. Column A consists of associate names and Column B is the customers. There are hundreds of different customers and I am trying to count how many unique customers there are for each associate. With the below query I am getting the count for all sales and not unique count. For instance Eli has 10 total sales, but only from 3 unique customers and I keep getting count 10.

=QUERY('Edited New Data'!A1:U14425,"SELECT A,
COUNT(B)
WHERE A = 'Maude' OR A = 'James ' OR A = 'Ross' OR A = 'Sam' OR A = 'Eli ' OR A = 'Daniel' OR A = 'Chrissy'
GROUP BY A
ORDER BY A ASC")

I have been searching for anything that will help return the unique query, but I have not been able to figure it out yet. I need the query function specifically so I can build a dynamic dashboard and not a static one. Any help is most appreciated.

With the below query I am getting the count for all sales and not unique count. For instance Eli has 10 total sales but only from 3 unique customers and I keep getting count 10.

=QUERY('Edited New Data'!A1:U14425,"SELECT A,
COUNT(B)
WHERE A = 'Maude' OR A = 'James ' OR A = 'Ross' OR A = 'Sam' OR A = 'Eli ' OR A = 'Daniel' OR A = 'Chrissy'
GROUP BY A
ORDER BY A ASC")

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a first instance of grouping by B so you can get the list of all customers and wrap in a new query where you finally count the amount of unique customers:

```
=QUERY(QUERY('Edited New Data'!A1:U14425,"SELECT A, B,COUNT(B) WHERE A = 'Maude' OR A = 'James ' OR A = 'Ross' OR A = 'Sam' OR A = 'Eli ' OR A = 'Daniel' OR A = 'Chrissy' GROUP BY A,B ORDER BY A ASC"),"Select Col1, Count(Col2) group by Col1")
```

Comment: `matches` method may simplify multiple `OR` logic. like `WHERE A matches 'Maude|James|Ross|Sam|Eli|Daniel|Chrissy'`.